# What preposion is suited to?

Tags: prepositions

What preposion is suited to the following sentence,  *in* or *by* or *at*?

> our team introduced practical processes and possible solutions available **in** our/the company.

And if there is some better way to write that, please show me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idiomatic choice would be

Available *to*...

But once the solution has been introduced, is it really still a "possible" solution?

I would make this into two clauses:

Our team introduced new practical processes to the company, and (some verb) potential solutions for .....

Comment: Our team made/introduced possible solutions and practical processes available to our/the company.